# cakephp javascript dynamic update

Tags: javascript, cakephp, for-loop

all creating a cakephp(using 2.1.2) page. we prompt the user to enter how many fields they are after(an int) and then we want the page to use a for-loop for the number entered.

here is the code for the add page

```
<h2>Please select how many fields you wish to add</h2></br>


<?php
print $this->Session->flash('flash', array('element' => 'alert'));

echo $this->Form->create('Field', array('action'=>'add'));

For(int i=0; i<'flash'; i++)
{
echo $this->Form->input('name',array('label'=>'Please Enter Field Name: ', 'type'=>'text')); 
echo $this->Form->input('description',array('label'=>'Please Enter Field Description: ', 'type'=>'text')); 
}
echo $this->Form->end('Click Here To Submit Template');

?>
```

here is the code for the alert

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    prompt('How many fields?','<?php print $message; ?>');
</script>
```

the question is how do we create a variable with the alert.ctp then be able to use that variable for a for loop to print out a form that takes user input.

EDIT:

Javascript function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var number_of_fields=prompt("How many fields?",'<?php print $message; ?>');
var field_html="";
for (i=0; i<number_of_fields; i++)
{
  field_html +='<input type="text" name="data[FIELD]['+i+'][name]">';
}
$("#FORMID").append(field_html); 

</script>
```

View:

```
<?php
print $this->Session->flash('flash', array('element' => 'alert'));

echo $this->Form->create('Field', array('action'=>'add'));



echo $this->Form->end('Click Here To Submit Template');

?>
```

Get no errors now, but cant display any fields. What do we put in the view to print the fields (which will be more input- so user can create a field)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we are getting the value of no: of required in javascript , i recommend to create fields also in javascript by following conventions used by cakephp to create input fields. So you can use javascript for loop and concat the fields in to a js variable and insert this html inputs to the form using javascript.

eg:

```
var number_of_fields=prompt("How many fields?",'<?php print $message; ?>');
var field_html="";
for (i=0; i<number_of_fields; i++)
{
  field_html +='<input type="text" name="data[MODELNAME]['+i+'][name]">';
}
$("#FORMID").append(field_html);
```

i hope this would make sense

Comment: Just edited the code @Sreeni. what do we put in the view if the Javasctipt function has the for loop?